# Classes with ValueType parameters

Tags: scala, class, constructor

I wrote the following simple program:

```
object Main extends App {
  println(s"${classOf[MyValueClass].getSimpleName}")
  val pt = classOf[MyClass].getDeclaredConstructors.asInstanceOf[Array[Constructor[MyClass]]].iterator.next.getParameterTypes
  pt.asInstanceOf[Array[Class[_]]] foreach { c =>
    println (c.getSimpleName)
  }
}

case class MyValueClass(v: Int) extends AnyVal

class MyClass(v: MyValueClass)
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/6YhHeB)

The program prints:

```
MyValueClass
int
```

But I expected it would print

```
MyValueClass
MyValueClass
```

Why is the parameters of the constructor `int`, not `MyValueClass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `MyValueClass` is extending `AnyVal` with only one `val Int` parameter.

> The type at compile time is Wrapper, but at runtime, the representation is an Int
>   http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html

ByteCode:

```
scala> :javap -c MyClass
Compiled from "<console>"
public class $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$MyClass {
  public $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$MyClass(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #19                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

as you can see the *bytecode*, the `MyClass` constructor parameter has been dealt as `int` primitive type after compiling.